# pyTelegramApiBot Ограничение по времени на нажатие кнопки

Tags: python, telebot

**У меня есть готовые кнопки в боте и я хочу что бы при нажатии некоторых из них ставилось ограничение.
Например пользователь нажимает на кнопку, а когда пытается нажать сразу второй раз то выскакивает сообщение "Вы недавно воспользовались этой функцией, повторите позже" ну или на крайний случай без сообщения, но просто что бы кнопка не работала какое то время**

Answer (score 1):

Запоминать последнее время нажатия, при клике проверять на то, прошло ли нужное количество времени, если нет, то выводить всплывающее окно.

В telebot это делается путем обращения к `answer_callback_query`